# phpmyadmin not working because i changed permissions and don't know how to change it back

Tags: permissions, apache2, mysql, lamp, phpmyadmin

I installed LAMPP and it worked fine, but i somehow managed to change the permission of the folder /opt/lampp/ to 777 by using this command

```
sudo chmod 777 -f /opt/lampp -R
```

My plans was to do:

```
sudo chmod 777 -f /opt/lampp/htdocs/ -R
```

And now when I'm going to *localhost/phpmyadmin* in the browser i get this error:
[image]

Could someone help me to fix this?

Comment: why not reinstall phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to issue this command:

`chmod 0755 config.inc.php`

PMA doesn't want the `config.inc.php` to be world writable, in your case, you made it world writable by `chmod 777`. If it doesn't work, try to issue the command below:

`chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin`

This will do a recursive chmod on your phpmyadmin folder.

If it still doesn't work, try to remove the phpmyadmin installation and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the direct permission to `/opt/htdocs`.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/htdocs
```

This will permit you to open apache access. solve this issue

```
chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin
```