# How to change directory permission from read-write to read-only

Tags: permissions, phpmyadmin, xampp, read-only, elementary

I'm an elementary-os user and I recently installed XAMPP to practice PHP. At first, I had to give read-write permission to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`, in order to create the project files.

But accidentally, I have given read-write permission to `/opt/lampp/` instead of `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`. I used following command.

```
$ sudo chmod -R 0777 /opt/lampp/
```

Now, when I tried to go to `phpMyAdmin` in browser it says, **Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable!**

I'm guessing, changing the directory's permission to it's default state (read-only) will solve this. I tried googling but couldn't find any working solution. Please help!

Comment: Elementary OS has it's own StackExchange site now.

Comment: Is this okay? Solutions I find for my problems always relate to ubuntu platform and all most all of them they works fine. That's why I  asked this question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on my own Google-fu, I was able to find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/374944/phpmyadmin-not-working-because-i-changed-permissions-and-dont-know-how-to-chang) that describes your issue similarly.

Try the following:

```
chmod 755 -R /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin
```

To fix the permissions of `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: @Rinzwind - why is that?

Comment: @codingman - It worked! :)

Comment: Nice :P. Glad I could help.