# Plex doesn't see folders in /home

Tags: 22.04, plex

Hardware: Processor amd athlon 64 x2 dual core processor 4000+ Motherboard: Asus m2n-mx se rev. 2.01g Ram: 1GB

Ubuntu Server Version: 22.04

I'm new to Linux. And English its not my main language sorry for errors if there's any

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change directory permission from read-write to read-only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792401/how-to-change-directory-permission-from-read-write-to-read-only)

Answer (score 0):

you need to give Plex permission to read directory with this command:

`sudo chmod -R 755 /home/your_username/`